# Edit search terms for all shops? (Or how to improve search)

Tags: multistore, search

Our products are named with the following system:

`XX #`

Where XX is a two letter code followed by a space and a number.

Unfortunately this is causing our search results to be less than optimal because, for example, searching for `AB 1` will result in everything with the number `1` to appear as well as, from what I can tell, `AB`.

We tried implementing search synonyms so that `AB 1` will instead return the results for `AB1` (minus whitespace), which works, but is now an issue because we have four shops (multilingual) and Magento doesn't seem to allow the scope of search term editing to span all the shops.

Is there any work around to this, or any suggestions for improving our results in this particular case? Other terms are working quite well (colour, product type etc)

Answer (score 1):

Could you not extend to search query to save synonyms against all stores buy the following steps.

1. Change the admin section to include the global store in the drop down, code is in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Search_Edit_Form`,
2. Update the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Query::loadByQuery` function to select the default store term or the site specific one if available,

I am not sure if both these changes will be enough but looking into the code it would appear so.